# Rust, attempt to add with overflow, large numbers

Tags: rust, numbers, overflow

I wrote a rust code to find Fibonacci numbers. It works for smaller numbers. For large numbers. I am getting error= thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to add with overflow', src/main.rs:13:20
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

The code is as follows

'''

```
fn main() {
 for n in 1..95 {
    let curr = fib(n);
    println!(" fibonacci {} is {}", n, curr);
 }
 println!("after 93th fibonacci, the value becomes too large for addition.");
 }

 fn fib(n: u8) -> u64 {
 let mut prev: u64 = 0;
 let mut curr: u64 = 1;
 for _ in 1..n {
    let next = prev + curr;
    prev = curr;
    curr = next;
 }
 curr
}
```

'''

How can I make it work for large numbers? Can we use smart box pointers to store large numbers on heap?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make it work for large numbers?

You have to use a "bignum"-type library (can't help you pick one because I've no idea about the landscape).

> Can we use smart box pointers to store large numbers on heap?

You can but if you're still using fixed-size integers that won't change anything: u64 is 64 bits and that's it. fib(94) needs 65 bits, so can't fit. You could use [u128](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u128.html) which would work until `fib(186)` (included) if you just want to run to fib(95).

Comment: thanks. I will search for bigmun type libraries.